# Bootstrap navbar collapse isn't collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar from bootstrap that isn't collapsing. I have JQuery placed before bootstrap and all CDNJ in the right place but still isn't working.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  navbar-light ">
            <div class="container">
              
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="d-inline-block align-top">
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav ">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.php">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="services.php">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Our Work</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am using Bootstrap 5

Edit: I solved the problem just removed the integrity from bootstrap.bundle.min.js and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Using the button from Bootstrap docs with your id seems to work:

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Edit: maybe you were using the wrong documentation from a previous version.